# ROS Answers SE migration: gtest-config

Tags: ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I upgraded from diamondback to electric. Compiling my sources with rosmake I get

[rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/roslisp/cmake/roslisp.cmake
[rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/rospy/cmake/rospy.cmake
[rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/cmake/roscpp.cmake
CMake Error at /opt/ros/electric/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:448 (message):
Failed to invoke gtest-config

Am I missing a (kubuntu) package?
libgtest-dev is already installed on my machine. Unfortunately, it does not contain the gtest-config script.

Any ideas?

Tobias

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12100/gtest-config/) by [Tobias](https://answers.ros.org/users/825/tobias/) on ROS Answers with karma: 156 on 2011-11-25

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When upgrading from one ROS distribution to the next, it is generally a good idea to completely rebuild any working tree previously compiled using the previous version.

```
$ rosmake <your_packages> --pre-clean
```

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6